# Can't pass a nested object to res.render()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I want to access a variable on client-side javascript, [through jade](http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#variables), passed on [form the server (node)](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render).

So I make a nested object:

```
var clientData = 
  {clientData:{
    title: 'Title',
    body: "body",
    appadress: 'localhost' || req.host,
    socketport: socketport,
  } }
```

then pass this object to jade ([via res.render](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render))..

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  clientData.clientData.appadress = req.host;
  res.render('index.jade', clientData)});
```

which in jade is recieves as.. (i believe)

```
clientData:{
    title: 'Title',
    body: "body",
    appadress: 'localhost' || req.host,
    socketport: socketport,
  }
```

Then I could pass that on to client-side javascript as a **single** object.

```
script.
  var clientData = #{clientData}
```

But this isn't working.

Does `res.render()` not take nested objects like that or something else the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't render objects with `#{...}`, because that stringifies the object (similar to this: `{}.toString()`, which yields `[object Object]`).

Instead, you need to convert the variable to JSON first, and make sure Jade doesn't escape the output:

```
var clientData = !{ JSON.stringify(clientData) };
```

**EDIT**: here's a simple standalone test (but the same principles would apply to using Jade through Express):

```
// app.jade
var jade  = require('jade');

jade.renderFile('test.jade', {
  filename  : 'test.jade', // These two properties are only for `renderFile`,
  pretty    : true,        // you don't need to include them with`res.render`
  clientData:{
    title     : 'Title',
    body      : 'body',
    appadress : 'localhost',
    socketport: 8888,
  }
}, function(err, html) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(html);
});

// test.jade
!!!
html
  head
    script.
      var clientData = !{ JSON.stringify(clientData) };
  body
    h1 Hello World

// Output:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>var clientData = {"title":"Title","body":"body","appadress":"localhost","socketport":1234};</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I only just noticed that you seem to be using `clientData` as a shared variable, and only set `clientData.clientData.appadress` from each request. This will cause problems because the `clientData` variable is shared across all requests and one request might overwrite the `appaddress` property just as another request will be rendering the template (showing the overwritten property).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But I can't get this to work either.. Firstly, with `!{}` it gives an 'unexpected token `.`' error. (btw, what does this do?) So I have to omit it `clientData = JSON.stringify(clientData);`. And secondly, even after passing the variable after JSONifying it, a simple `div= clientData` in jade outputs nothing. Can I please bother you to post a more complele code, with the jade-side code as well?

Comment: @laggingreflex I updated my answer to give an example (and I notices a potential bug in your code, too)